# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have checked my query and the number and type of columns are identical (9 columns - the datatype in my temporary table is identical to the column I'm selecting from).

I can't understand why the error is appearing. I'm using a similar query in the same stored procedure and it works fine.

```
declare @HTMLSelect nvarchar(max),
@HTMLWhere nvarchar(max),
@timeperiod int,
@deptcode varchar(10),
@sql nvarchar(max)

set @deptcode = null
set @timeperiod = '-14'

SET @HTMLSelect = N'SELECT TOP 200
            client.clname as [Client]
            , file.mfile as [fileNo]
            , file.mopendt as [OpenDate]
            , file.mdesc1 as [file]
            , deptlab.head1 as [Dept]
            , prac.pdesc as [fileType]
            , file.mbillaty as [Code]
            , user.tkfirst + '' '' + user.tklast AS [Username]
            , file.mrefer as [ReferralType]
            FROM         user AS user
            INNER JOIN
                file AS file ON user.tkinit = file.mbillaty 
            INNER JOIN
                client AS client ON client.clnum = file.mclient
            INNER JOIN
                deptlab AS deptlab ON deptlab.delcode = file.mdept 
            INNER JOIN
                praccode AS prac ON prac.[pcode] = file.mprac
            '
            set @deptcode = null
            set @HTMLWhere = N'
            WHERE      
            (user.tkeflag = ''Y'') 
            AND file.mrefer like ''%staff%''
            AND (file.mopendt >= DATEADD(dd, '  + CAST ( @timeperiod as [nvarchar]) +  ', GETDATE()))
            '           
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#staffTable') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            Truncate TABLE #staffTable
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE #staffTable(
                Client varchar(60)
                ,fileNo varchar(15)
                ,OpenDate datetime
                ,file varchar(60)
                ,Dept varchar(40)
                ,fileType varchar(48)
                ,FECode varchar(8)
                ,Username varchar(150)
                ,ReferralType varchar(60)
            )

            set @sql = @HTMLSelect + @HTMLWhere
            INSERT INTO #staffTable EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

A typical set of results for the query in `@HTMLSelect` and `@HTMLWhere` would be as follows:

```
+----------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+
| Client   | FileNo        | OpenDate   | File   | Dept         | FileType | Code | Username     | ReferralType |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+
| Client 1 | 055311.000001 | 16/07/2018 | File 1 | Department D | Type 1   | 123  | Peter Parker | Type Y       |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+
| Client 2 | 079934.000001 | 17/07/2018 | File 2 | Department A | Type 9   | 566  | Kevin Smith  | Type C       |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+
| Client 3 | 135353.005351 | 01/07/2018 | File 3 | Department V | Type 6   | 353  | Jason Mewes  | Type B       |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

I've isolated various parts of this and it works - it's when it's all together that it breaks! It is definitely failing on the insert but if the columns are in the correct order and all the datatypes match, I don't get why it is failing.

Using `sp_executesql` means that I can't insert by specifying both columns and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [file]
(
    mfile VARCHAR(15),
    mopendt DATETIME,
    mdesc1 VARCHAR(60),
    mbillaty VARCHAR(8),
    mrefer VARCHAR(60),
    mclient INT,
    mdept INT,
    mprac INT
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.[file]
(
    mfile,
    mopendt,
    mdesc1,
    mbillaty,
    mrefer,
    mclient,
    mdept,
    mprac
)
VALUES
('mf1', GETDATE(), 'md1', 'mb1', 'staff', 1, 1, 1);
GO 
CREATE TABLE [user]
(
    tkfirst VARCHAR(50),
    tklast VARCHAR(100),
    tkinit VARCHAR(8),
    tkeflag VARCHAR(5)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.[user]
(
    tkfirst,
    tklast,
    tkinit,
    tkeflag
)
VALUES
('tkf1', 'thkl1', 'mb1', 'Y');
GO
CREATE TABLE client
(
    clname VARCHAR(60),
    clnum INT
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.client
(
    clname,
    clnum
)
VALUES
('cl1', 1);
GO
CREATE TABLE deptlab
(
    head1 VARCHAR(40),
    delcode INT
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.deptlab
(
    head1,
    delcode
)
VALUES
('h1', 1);
GO
CREATE TABLE praccode
(
    pdesc VARCHAR(48),
    pcode INT
);
INSERT INTO dbo.praccode
(
    pdesc,
    pcode
)
VALUES
('pd1', 1);
```

So the following code should work:

```
DECLARE @HTMLSelect NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @HTMLWhere NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @timeperiod INT,
        @deptcode VARCHAR(10),
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @deptcode = NULL;
SET @timeperiod = '-14';

SET @HTMLSelect
    = N'SELECT TOP 200
       client.clname  AS [Client],
       [file].mfile  AS [fileNo],
       [file].mopendt  AS [OpenDate],
       [file].mdesc1 AS [file],
       deptlab.head1  AS [Dept],
       prac.pdesc  AS [fileType],
       [file].mbillaty  AS [Code],
       [user].tkfirst + '' '' + [user].tklast AS [Username],
       [file].mrefer AS  [ReferralType]
FROM [user] AS [user]
    INNER JOIN [file] AS [file]
        ON [user].tkinit = [file].mbillaty
    INNER JOIN client AS client
        ON client.clnum = [file].mclient
    INNER JOIN deptlab AS deptlab
        ON deptlab.delcode = [file].mdept
    INNER JOIN praccode AS prac
        ON prac.[pcode] = [file].mprac
            ';
SET @deptcode = NULL;
SET @HTMLWhere
    = N'
            WHERE      
            ([user].tkeflag = ''Y'') 
            AND [file].mrefer like ''%staff%''
            AND ([file].mopendt >= DATEADD(dd, ' + CAST(@timeperiod AS [NVARCHAR]) + N', GETDATE()))
            ';
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#staffTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #staffTable;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #staffTable
    (
        Client VARCHAR(60),
        fileNo VARCHAR(15),
        OpenDate DATETIME,
        [file] VARCHAR(60),
        Dept VARCHAR(40),
        fileType VARCHAR(48),
        FECode VARCHAR(8),
        Username VARCHAR(150),
        ReferralType VARCHAR(60)
    );
END;

SET @sql = @HTMLSelect + @HTMLWhere;

PRINT @sql;

INSERT INTO #staffTable
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #staffTable
```

Comment: The columns I am selecting share the same datatype as the temporary table (I've checked and double checked this) so I shouldn't be having to cast everything. It's a very old system, hence SQL 2005, which has no primary keys.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out in the end -variables such as `@sql` were being overwritten elsewhere. I created new variables for this section and with some of your changes, it worked!